# One-click full backup & dropbox sync in Titanium Backup?

Tags: titanium-backup

Is it possible to make a full backup of everything and then it sync into dropbox (and repeat if syncing was unsuccessful) with a one click? I'd like to just launch a backup procedure and go sleeping knowing that when I wake up, everything that could be done was done... and Titanium Backup's interface is so confusing to me.

I've got a pro version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 4.8.2 you can automatically synchronise to Dropbox (or Box.net) with each scheduled backup:

- Go to Schedules in the main menu
- Select a schedule or create a new one
- Fiddle with the time settings to your heart's content
- Select "Sync to Dropbox" in the "When finished:" combo box at the bottom.

Could also be a good idea to adjust the "Connectivity modes" to synchronise over Wi-Fi only in the settings to avoid unnecessary data charges (if applicable).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know there actually is that "When finished:" field because it is hidden on my phone. The dialog box nicely ends with "Sunday" checkbox and there is no indication I could scroll down. Now if only I could create a shortcut in my launcher's drawer to run this schedule...

Answer (score 4):

I can trim to two clicks: 1 for Full backup to local storage & another for Dropbox sync.

**For Full Backup to Local Storage:**
1. Tap & hold on empty home screen area. Choose *Widgets*.
2. From Pop-up list, tap *Titanium Backup (Actions)*. Again, tap *Action*.
3. On next screen, choose *Backup all user apps + system data* & tap *Create Widget* button.
4. Done! Now, all you have to do is to tap this widget from your home screen.

**For Full Sync to Dropbox:**
1. Make sure you've already enabled & configured Dropbox sync from *Menu* ~> *Preferences*.
2. From *Preferences*, tap *Dropbox settings* & then *Labels to synchronize*. Check *Synchronize everything* checkbox & tap *OK*.
3. Done! Now, all you need is to open app & tap *Sync to Dropbox now !* button at bottom from *Overview* tab..

**Main Method For Full Backup to Local Storage (To shoot out your confusion):**
1. Tap *Backup/Restore* tab.
2. Tap *Click to edit filters* just below tab bar (right-side). Make sure all radio buttons are set to *All* & there's no label are selected (if you've labels). Tap *Apply* button on top-right.
3. Hit Physical *Menu* button & choose *Batch*.
4. On next screen, tap *RUN* button left to *Backup all user apps + system data*. Tap *Run the batch operation* button on top.

**Go really for a sleep:**
Setup & enable a full backup schedule profile from *Schedules* tab. It will be enough if you just enable the two default schedule profiles. You can change its backup frequency after tapping *Edit* button.

So, in the last, you just need 1 click: 0 for Full backup & 1 for Dropbox sync! :)

**What about 0 clicks??**
Install [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) & link TB's Backup directory to a folder in Dropbox (free version supports 1 directory linking which is enough for this). It'll sync backups with Dropbox automatically (make sure `Auto Sync` is check in settings). So, you don't need even that one click...